# Writing a script file to test a function? (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I'm currently working on a program where I have a function that runs and does a bunch of things. I wrote a script over the summer at work that could take dummy input and pass it to a function call and then all I had to do was open a command prompt and say `node test.js`.

Unfortunately I don't remember what that code looked like exactly but I know it was fairly simple.

For simplicity's sake, lets say I have a function:

```
var double_num = function(num){
    return num*2;
}
```

contained in a file called double.js

and I also have a blank javascript file test.js. How complicated is it to call `double_num` from test.js with something in the file like:

```
var result = double_num(5);
console.log(result);
```

from the command line using `node test.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to export `double.js` as a module, and then import that module into `test.js`. Should look something like this:

```
// double.js

var double_num = function(num){
    return num*2;
}

// export your `double_num` function as a module so 
// we can import this elsewhere in our programs
modules.export = double_num;
```

And in `test.js` make sure to include `double.js` by using its relative path to `test.js`. Assuming that they're in the same directory, it might look something like this:

```
// test.js

// Import `double_num` from the file we just exported it from
var double_num = require('./double_num');

var result = double_num(5);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you! I attempted to upvote this answer but do not have enough reputation for it to display :(. But thank you! @Nick

Comment: @Ryan Happy I was able to help! You can mark this answer as correct (I believe there is a certain amount of time you need to wait before you can do so, though)

Comment: Ah! You're right, I marked it correct. Didn't see that checkmark there. (Sorry, major stackoverflow newb).